# why the cookie value is not updated at once when i submit the form?

Tags: php, cookies

why the cookie value is not updated at once when i submit the form ?
when I submit the form ,the output refer_id is still the old one ,but when I refresh the browser , it change ,why can not it change at once?

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['refer_id'])){
    setcookie('refer_id',$_GET['refer_id'],time()+3600);
}
print_r($_COOKIE);
 ?>
<p>cookie refer_id:<?php echo $_COOKIE['refer_id'];?></p>
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="refer_id" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: The cookie will not be set until after the page is rendered by the client. Submit the form, then refresh the page, you should see the updated value.

Comment: You're reading the cookie that is on the server; when you `setcookie()`, you're sending an update to the browser, which then must represent it to the server. So you're reading the static `$_COOKIE` value that was already given to the server when you read it out on the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine it like this:

1. Some client asks for your page. You `setcookie()` and send that in the header.
2. That client receives that cookie header, puts it in it's cookie store.
3. When making the next request, that cookie is sent with the header back to the server.
4. The server sees *that* cookie, sets it to the superglobal `$_COOKIE`.
5. Your server "updates" that cookie value *for the client* with a new `setcookie()` directive.
6. Before responding, you read to output the `$_COOKIE` value which is *still the last cookie value*.
7. The browser receives the new header, updates that cookie's value, and displays the content, *with the old value* read from the server.

`setcookie()` does not affect `$_COOKIE`, unless you count the roundtrip back.

Rinse, repeat.

Comment: so any method to get the the cookie value I updated at once when I submit the form?

Comment: When you `setcookie()`, you can `$_COOKIE['thekey'] = $thevalue;` at the same time?

Comment: but how to set the cookie expire time if I use $_COOKIE['thekey'] = $thevalue;

Comment: You set it like you have; you just won't *see* that setting during that server's processing of that request unless you sync that `$_GET['refer_id']` to the corresponding `$_COOKIE['refer_id']`. To set the expire time, you use `setcookie()`.