# codeigniter unsetting session works unexpectedly

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, user-data

I submit form to `controller/complete` action, set

```
$this->session->set_userdata('success', 3);
```

and then redirect to `index` action with `redirect('controller', 'refresh');`.

In my view I get

```
$success = $this->session->userdata('success');
```

do some work and then

```
$this->session->set_userdata('success', 0);
```

And it works fine, but when I reload page (it is an `index` action), I still get in `$success` `3`, not `0`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many problems with codeigniter DB Session, and thus refuse to use it, to include the session not actually properly updating.

If you are interested I created a PHP Session based class that acts as a replacement, it benefits from backward compatability, but also a much easier way of using it.

Check out my Gist: https://gist.github.com/chazmead/1688becbcf11f897e962

To install you will need to replace the CI Session config in application/config/config.php to:

```
$config['session'] = (object)array(
    'UID' => 'MY_SESSION_KEY',
    'sess_expiration' => 7200,
    'match_ip' => False,
    'match_user_agent' => False
);
```

Then install the file to application/models/session.php

then instead of loading the CI session, just load this session model.
Using this is very easy, just assign variables to the session and it saves automatically, it also locks and unlocks the session so that async requests don't get locked up (which is a problem with PHP sessions)

For full backward compatability you may need to use `$this->session = &$this->Session` after loading the new model, otherwise you will have to make sure your calling session using `Session` (Uppercase S) as this is how CI models work.  or install as a library instead..

Answer (score 0):

The codeigniter by default managing `session` in COOKIE, more info

[why the cookie value is not updated at once when i submit the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352349/why-the-cookie-value-is-not-updated-at-once-when-i-submit-the-form?answertab=active#tab-top)

CI also provides setting to store session data in database table, if you store session in table this would work fine.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: In `complete` action I set the cookie (`$this->session->set_userdata('success', 3);`)and send it to client.
Then I redirect to `index`, so the client sends back me that cookie.
I read from cookie (`$this->session->userdata('success');`), update it (`$this->session->set_userdata('success', 0);`) and send it back.
So, on page reload I would get new modified cookie with `success` value of `0`. But no matter how many times I reload the page, I still get `3`